# Can VideoView be detach and reattached without stopping the stream?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-videoview, vitamio

I'm building an app where the user clicks on a button to show a video full screen. Initially the video is attached to a view inside a ViewPager. To be able to show it fullscreen I detach it from its parent and reattach it to the root view. This works fine, except when the video is switched to fullscreen while playing. When I detach a playing VideoView it just stop and I need to restart it. This is not acceptable since the video starts buffering before resume. Here the part of the code where the detach is done:

```
    final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent);

    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            parent.removeView(mVideoView);

            LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            root.addView(mVideoView, lp);
        }
    });
```

Depending of the device, I have a different log error. Probably because the actual video player  is provided by the manufacturer and not the Android SDK. Here are the error logs for a Nexus 7:

```
10-30 20:26:18.618: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(124): NvMMDecTVMRDestroyParser Begin 
10-30 20:26:18.618: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(124): --------- Closing TVMR Frame Delivery Thread -------------
10-30 20:26:18.678: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(124): ------- NvAvpClose -------
10-30 20:26:18.678: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(124): NvMMDecTVMRDestroyParser Done 
10-30 20:26:18.678: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(124): NvMMLiteTVMRDecPrivateClose Done
```

I haven't been able to detach the video without stopping it. I tried using SurfaceView or TextureView without success.

I also tried finding a third party video player. I found a commercial one (http://www.vitamio.org/) that I can't really use for business reason. I found an open source one, that hasn't been updated in the last year (https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/).

I'm currently targeting Android 4.2 or better on tablet only.

---

### Note that the ViewPager is not fullscreen. So I can't use LayoutParams to make the video fullscreen. I need to remove the VideoView from the parent in the ViewPager and add it to the root view to be able to show it fullscreen.

The URL I'm testing with: http://bellvps1.cpl.delvenetworks.com/media/e1b3e24ecb944abd8f4ed823a0b76ddc/68f78d35296243bfb46d2418f03f2fd0/bande-annonce---the-secret-life-of-walter-mitty-1-9efcc5c6e52ac07a3edf84a1b21967995b7796a2.m3u8

Comment: If you have time try to extend VideoView and override `onDetachedFromWindow()`: use an empty one do not call super.

Comment: Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987042/videoview-onresume-loses-buffered-portion-of-the-video/10368107#10368107) may give you some clue on how to do it using SurfaceView.

Comment: Why not use `seekTo()` method in combination with `getCurrentPosition()`? I can see `VideoView` implements `MediaController`.

Comment: Instead of removing from "parent" just set LayoutParams of "parent" full screen (MATCH_PARENT), so i think you don't required to remove videoview from parent and add to root view. Here you have tried to resize only videoview, try also resize your "parent" view to full screen and comment "parent.removeView(mVideoView);" code.

Comment: @HirenDabhi Setting the parent to MATCH_PARENT cannot work because I want to keep the same layout in the ViewPager

Comment: @M-WaJeEh I cannot use seekTo because it doesn't start right away. I want the transition to fullscreen to be unnoticable to the user.

Answer (score 12):

This effect can be achieved using a `TextureView`.
Essentially what you do is create a `MediaPlayer` instance, `prepare()` it and start() it, you can then use `MediaPlayer.setSurface()` method on any `TextureView` to change the surface as the video is playing without any changes to `MediaPlayer` object state, as stated in android's docs for `setSurface()` method:

`This method can be called in any state and calling it does not change the object state.`

Please note this implementation is for the sake of demonstration, you should probably use `mediaplayer.prepareAsync()` and wait for a callback with `onPreparedListener()`, you will also need to set the correct dimensions for the second `TextureView` according to your video size, handle orientation changes and of course handle exceptions properly wherever needed.

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Switch to second surface" />

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/tv_full"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String VIDEO_URI = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4";

    private TextureView tvFull;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(VIDEO_URI));
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager)).setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
            @Override public int getCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                return view == o;
            }

            @Override public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                final TextureView tv = new TextureView(MainActivity.this);

                tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
                    @Override public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
                        tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(null);
                        mp.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
                        mp.start();
                    }

                    @Override public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {}

                    @Override public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {}
                });

                if (tv.isAvailable()) {
                    tv.getSurfaceTextureListener().onSurfaceTextureAvailable(tv.getSurfaceTexture(),
                            tv.getWidth(), tv.getHeight());
                }

                container.addView(tv, 0);
                return tv;
            }

            @Override public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View) object);
            }
        });

        tvFull = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.tv_full);

        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                tvFull.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
                    @Override public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
                        tvFull.setSurfaceTextureListener(null);
                        mp.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
                    }

                    @Override public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

                    }
                });

                if (tvFull.isAvailable()) {
                    tvFull.getSurfaceTextureListener().onSurfaceTextureAvailable(tvFull.getSurfaceTexture(),
                            tvFull.getWidth(), tvFull.getHeight());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works technically, but it's not the user experience I'm looking for. :)
First, the video stops for a few milliseconds. It's unfortunately noticeable. Secondly, with my test url (see above) the videoview is not refreshed 100% when the surface changed. So until a frame refreshed the screen completely, I see black pixels. Thanks anyway for the effort. You deserve the bounty. But I don't think what I want to do is doable. :)

Comment: @Thierry-DimitriRoy this might be due to specific encoding settings you're using for this video, perhaps this can help further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299412/androids-mediaplayer-setsurface-while-on-paused-state

Comment: I don't think so. MPEG is built such that only the pixels that changes between frame are drawn. That's why I have these black portion on the screen. And there is no way to force a refresh of the screen. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of how the video player works, but my hunch is you have to:

```
Override onSaveInstanceState to save the place in the video (maybe a timestamp?)

Override onRestoreInstanceState to reload the video and seek to the point saved in step 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried this but hope it may help you,

```
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent);

    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);//assuming this full screen

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // parent.removeView(mVideoView);
            LayoutParams parentParam = parent.getLayoutParams();
            parentParam.height = root.getLayoutParams().height;
            parentParam.width = root.getLayoutParams().width;
            parent.setLayoutParams(parentParam);
            LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            root.addView(mVideoView, lp);
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use textureview with this modification:

```
@Override 
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface (surfaceTexture));}
            }
```

Upd: And full code:
player2.java:

```
public class player2 extends TextureView
    implements MediaPlayerControl {
    private String TAG = "TextureVideoView";
    // settable by the client
    private Uri         mUri;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;

    // all possible internal states
    private static final int STATE_ERROR              = -1;
    private static final int STATE_IDLE               = 0;
    private static final int STATE_PREPARING          = 1;
    private static final int STATE_PREPARED           = 2;
    private static final int STATE_PLAYING            = 3;
    private static final int STATE_PAUSED             = 4;
    private static final int STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED = 5;

    private static int mCurrentState;
    private static int mTargetState;


    // All the stuff we need for playing and showing a video
    static public SurfaceTexture sf;
    static public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private int         mAudioSession;
    private int         mVideoWidth;
    private int         mVideoHeight;
    private int         mSurfaceWidth;
    private int         mSurfaceHeight;
    private  MediaController mMediaController;
    private OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener;
    private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener;
    private int         mCurrentBufferPercentage;
    private OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener;
    private OnInfoListener  mOnInfoListener;
    private int         mSeekWhenPrepared;  // recording the seek position while preparing
    private static boolean     mCanPause;
    private static boolean     mCanSeekBack;
    private static boolean     mCanSeekForward;
    private Context mContext;

    public player2(Context context) {
        super(context);
       initVideoView();
    }

    public player2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        initVideoView();
    }

    public player2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initVideoView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //Log.i("@@@@", "onMeasure(" + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec) + ", "
        //        + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec) + ")");

        int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {

            int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int widthSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // the size is fixed
                width = widthSpecSize;
                height = heightSpecSize;

                // for compatibility, we adjust size based on aspect ratio
                if ( mVideoWidth * height  < width * mVideoHeight ) {
                    //Log.i("@@@", "image too wide, correcting");
                    width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                } else if ( mVideoWidth * height  > width * mVideoHeight ) {
                    //Log.i("@@@", "image too tall, correcting");
                    height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                }
            } else if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // only the width is fixed, adjust the height to match aspect ratio if possible
                width = widthSpecSize;
                height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                if (heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && height > heightSpecSize) {
                    // couldn't match aspect ratio within the constraints
                    height = heightSpecSize;
                }
            } else if (heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // only the height is fixed, adjust the width to match aspect ratio if possible
                height = heightSpecSize;
                width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && width > widthSpecSize) {
                    // couldn't match aspect ratio within the constraints
                    width = widthSpecSize;
                }
            } else {
                // neither the width nor the height are fixed, try to use actual video size
                width = mVideoWidth;
                height = mVideoHeight;
                if (heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && height > heightSpecSize) {
                    // too tall, decrease both width and height
                    height = heightSpecSize;
                    width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                }
                if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && width > widthSpecSize) {
                    // too wide, decrease both width and height
                    width = widthSpecSize;
                    height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no size yet, just adopt the given spec sizes
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(player2.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(player2.class.getName());
    }

    public int resolveAdjustedSize(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
        return getDefaultSize(desiredSize, measureSpec);
    }

    private void initVideoView() {
        mContext = getContext();
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        mPendingSubtitleTracks = new Vector<Pair<InputStream, MediaFormat>>();
        if (mMediaPlayer==null)  {
        mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
        mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;}
    }

    public void setVideoPath(String path) {
        setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    }

    public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
        setVideoURI(uri, null);
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    private void setVideoURI(Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers) {
        mUri = uri;
        mHeaders = headers;
        mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    private Vector<Pair<InputStream, MediaFormat>> mPendingSubtitleTracks;

    public void stopPlayback() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
            mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;
        }
    }
    private void setListeners() {
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mSizeChangedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mErrorListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(mInfoListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mBufferingUpdateListener);
        mCurrentBufferPercentage = 0;
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    }
    private void openVideo() {
        if (mUri == null || sf == null) {
            // not ready for playback just yet, will try again later
            return;
        }
        // Tell the music playback service to pause
        // TODO: these constants need to be published somewhere in the framework.
       /* Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "pause");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(i);*/
        if (mMediaPlayer==null) {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            if (mAudioSession != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(mAudioSession);
            } else {
                mAudioSession = mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
            }
            setListeners();

            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface (sf));
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, mUri, mHeaders);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            // we don't set the target state here either, but preserve the
            // target state that was there before.
            mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARING;
            attachMediaController();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            mErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, 0);
            return;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            mErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, 0);
            return;
        } finally {
            mPendingSubtitleTracks.clear();
        }} else {
            setListeners();
        }
    }

    public void setMediaController(MediaController controller) {
        if (mMediaController != null) {
            mMediaController.hide();
        }
        mMediaController = controller;
        attachMediaController();
    }

    private void attachMediaController() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaController != null) {
            mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
            View anchorView = this.getParent() instanceof View ?
                (View)this.getParent() : this;
            mMediaController.setAnchorView(anchorView);
            mMediaController.setEnabled(isInPlaybackState());
        }
    }

    MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener mSizeChangedListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
                mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
                if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
                    getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
                    requestLayout();
                }
            }
        };

    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARED;

            mCanPause = mCanSeekBack = mCanSeekForward = true;

            if (mOnPreparedListener != null) {
                mOnPreparedListener.onPrepared(mMediaPlayer);
            }
            if (mMediaController != null) {
                mMediaController.setEnabled(true);
            }
            mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
            mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

            int seekToPosition = mSeekWhenPrepared;  // mSeekWhenPrepared may be changed after seekTo() call
            if (seekToPosition != 0) {
                seekTo(seekToPosition);
            }
            if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
                //Log.i("@@@@", "video size: " + mVideoWidth +"/"+ mVideoHeight);
                getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
                requestLayout();
                if (mSurfaceWidth == mVideoWidth && mSurfaceHeight == mVideoHeight) {
                    // We didn't actually change the size (it was already at the size
                    // we need), so we won't get a "surface changed" callback, so
                    // start the video here instead of in the callback.
                    if (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING) {
                        start();
                        if (mMediaController != null) {
                            mMediaController.show();
                        }
                    } else if (!isPlaying() &&
                        (seekToPosition != 0 || getCurrentPosition() > 0)) {
                        if (mMediaController != null) {
                            // Show the media controls when we're paused into a video and make 'em stick.
                            mMediaController.show(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // We don't know the video size yet, but should start anyway.
                // The video size might be reported to us later.
                if (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING) {
                    start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (mCurrentState == STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED) {
                return;
            }
                mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;
                mTargetState = STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;
                if (mMediaController != null) {
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }
                if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                    mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
                }
            }
        };

    private MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener mInfoListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            public  boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
                if (mOnInfoListener != null) {
                    mOnInfoListener.onInfo(mp, arg1, arg2);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

    private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener mErrorListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int framework_err, int impl_err) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + framework_err + "," + impl_err);
                mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
                mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
                if (mMediaController != null) {
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }

            /* If an error handler has been supplied, use it and finish. */
                if (mOnErrorListener != null) {
                    if (mOnErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, framework_err, impl_err)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (getWindowToken() != null) {
                   // Resources r = mContext.getResources();
                    int messageId;

                    if (framework_err == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK) {
                        messageId = R.string.VideoView_error_text_invalid_progressive_playback;
                    } else {
                        messageId = R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown;
                    }

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                        .setMessage(messageId)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.VideoView_error_button,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        /* If we get here, there is no onError listener, so
                                         * at least inform them that the video is over.
                                         */
                                    if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                                        mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

    private MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener mBufferingUpdateListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                mCurrentBufferPercentage = percent;
            }
        };

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the media file
     * is loaded and ready to go.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l)
    {
        mOnPreparedListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media file
     * has been reached during playback.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener l)
    {
        mOnCompletionListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an error occurs
     * during playback or setup.  If no listener is specified,
     * or if the listener returned false, TextureVideoView will inform
     * the user of any errors.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener l)
    {
        mOnErrorListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an informational event
     * occurs during playback or setup.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnInfoListener(OnInfoListener l) {
        mOnInfoListener = l;
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new SurfaceTextureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
            if (mMediaPlayer!=null) {
                mVideoWidth = mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
                mVideoHeight = mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
                if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
                    surface.setDefaultBufferSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
                    requestLayout();
                }}
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
           sf=surface;
           mSurfaceWidth = width;
           mSurfaceHeight = height;
            if (mMediaPlayer!=null) { mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface (surface));
          } 
            openVideo();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(final SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(final SurfaceTexture surface) {}
    };

    /*
     * release the media player in any state
     */
    private void release(boolean cleartargetstate) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mPendingSubtitleTracks.clear();
            mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
            if (cleartargetstate) {
                mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isInPlaybackState() && mMediaController != null) {
            toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isInPlaybackState() && mMediaController != null) {
            toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        boolean isKeyCodeSupported = keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL;
        if (isInPlaybackState() && isKeyCodeSupported && mMediaController != null) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK ||
                keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    pause();
                    mMediaController.show();
                } else {
                    start();
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }
                return true;
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
                if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    start();
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }
                return true;
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    pause();
                    mMediaController.show();
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void toggleMediaControlsVisiblity() {
        if (mMediaController.isShowing()) {
            mMediaController.hide();
        } else {
            mMediaController.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;
        }
        mTargetState = STATE_PLAYING;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                mCurrentState = STATE_PAUSED;
            }
        }
        mTargetState = STATE_PAUSED;
    }

    public void suspend() {
        release(false);
    }

    public void resume() {
        openVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int msec) {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(msec);
            mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
        } else {
            mSeekWhenPrepared = msec;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return isInPlaybackState() && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            return mCurrentBufferPercentage;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean isInPlaybackState() {
        return (mMediaPlayer != null &&
            mCurrentState != STATE_ERROR &&
            mCurrentState != STATE_IDLE &&
            mCurrentState != STATE_PREPARING);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return mCanPause;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return mCanSeekBack;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return mCanSeekForward;
    }

    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        if (mAudioSession == 0) {
            MediaPlayer foo = new MediaPlayer();
            mAudioSession = foo.getAudioSessionId();
            foo.release();
        }
        return mAudioSession;
    }

}
```

And some code of MainActivity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        static View frame1;
        static player2 textureView;
        static boolean pause=false;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            pause=false;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            pause=true;
            super.onPause();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            if ((player2.sf!=null)&&(pause==true)&&(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()==null)) {
                textureView.setSurfaceTexture(player2.sf);}
            super.onResume();
        }
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment  {


            public PlaceholderFragment() {}

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                        false);
                frame1=rootView.findViewById(R.id.frame1);


                textureView = (player2)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textureView1);
                textureView.setVideoPath("http://master255.org/res/Клипы/S/SKRILLEX/Skrillex - Summit (feat. Ellie Goulding) [Video by Pilerats].mp4");
                textureView.setMediaController(new mediac(getActivity(), frame1));
                if (player2.sf != null) {
                    if ((pause==false)&&(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()==null)) {
                        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(player2.sf);}
                }

                textureView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                        textureView.start();
                    }
                });
                return rootView;
            }
            public class mediac extends MediaController
            {

                public mediac(Context context, View anchor)
                {
                    super(context);
                    super.setAnchorView(anchor);
                }

                @Override
                public void setAnchorView(View view)
                {}

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: With my test url (see above) the videoview is not refreshed 100% when the surface changed. Thanks for the proposed solution anyway! :)

Comment: I have work example! test my project https://github.com/master255/TextureVideoPlayer

Answer (score 0):

VideoView extends SurfaceView and is dependent on the lifecycle of the surfaceView. When the surfaceView is destroyed the media player is released and the state is not preserved. as a result, when you detach the VideoView the surface is destroyed and the media player is released.